# Why does this loop cause a stack overflow?

Tags: jquery

I decided to mess around with jquery and make a simple axonometric map based game. It renders some of the map, then has an issue with stack. (Maximum call stack size exceeded)
I am just using background colors for the tiles for now.

[JS Bin Here](http://jsbin.com/xomes/9/edit)

```
var map = [
  "g","g","g","s","s",
  "g","g","s","s","w",
  "g","g","s","w","w",
  "g","g","s","w","w",
  "g","g","s","w","w"
];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var count = 0;
var background;
function init() { $.each( map, function( key, value ) {

    x += 30;
    y += 60;
  if (count > 4){
    x -= 120;
    y -= 360;
    count = 0;
  }
    if (value == "g"){background = "#00ff00";}
    if (value == "w"){background = "#0000ff";}
    if (value == "s"){background = "#ffff00";}

    $('.map_piece').clone().appendTo('body').css({'top' : x + 'px', 'left' : y + 'px','display' : 'block','background' : background});
      count ++;
});
                }

$('document').ready(function(){
 init(); 

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each iteration k, you clone 2^k items.

Instead of cloning an element, it might just be easier to create a new element each time:

```
$('<div class="map_piece">')
    .appendTo('body')
    .css({'top' : x + 'px', 'left' : y + 'px','display' : 'block','background' : background});
```

Comment: Thank you much for the correction and reason why it was happening. I am not too familiar with clone, I didn't realize I was cloning EVERY instance. Both answers are helpful, but since you answered first by 2 minutes... you'll get the check mark! :)

Answer (score 4):

Calling `$('.map_piece').clone()` clones all pieces that have been created thus far. This causes exponential growth in the number of cloned elements every time the loop runs. To do what you're intending to do, limit the clone to just one element by using `first()`.

```
$('.map_piece').first().clone().appendTo('body').css({'top' : x + 'px', 'left' : y + 'px','display' : 'block','background' : background});
```

Comment: Up vote! Thanks for showing me about first()! I see both methods and will try to remember them.